# How to access coefficients and gradients of neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks

I would like to test optimization for neural networks for that I need to access the weights/bias of the different layers and the derivatives of the output or a loss function with respect to these coefficients? Is there obvious way to do this using built-in functions? At some point

```
NetTrain
```

must access the coefficients, compute gradients and re-update them. I am aware of the function

```
NetInformation[network, "Arrays"]
```

which returns an association that gives the different coefficients. With some manipulation, eg:

```
Values@NetInformation[trained, "Arrays"]
```

it is possible to transform this output in an array that then can go inside of an optimizer code but this may not be the optimal way to do it. Moreover, I don't see in the documentation any way to compute gradients.
Also, what would be a good way to replace coefficients in the network?

Comment: Look up the documentation for NetPortGradient - that is what you want

Comment: @M.R. You should add that as an answer, it's the correct answer and limited extra information is needed